# What is causing the jump during this collapse or expand CSS transition?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-transitions

I realize there are CSS/JS animation libraries which would accomplish this, but I am learning CSS Transitions and would like to accomplish this with minimal JS.  (I quite enjoy CSS :)

I have several flex-item columns equally sized with `flex-grow: 1`.  I would like a click on a column header to shrink or expand the column, the header itself should remain visible (so that it may be clicked to expand).  As `display` is not an animateable CSS property, I am attempting this with a 2 second transition on `width: 0; opacity: 0;` on the flex-item content (other than the header) and `flex-grow: 0` on the flex-item itself.

I am trying eliminate an undesirable "jump" at the end of a collapse and at the start of an expand.

Despite being the same duration and presumably firing at the same time (after a class change on click), it seems the flex-grow transition is not synchronized with the width/opacity transition of the content, and so the flex-grow transition finishes "too early" (before the content is width 0), then jumps the final bit after the width transition finishes.  If I make the flex-grow transition longer (than the width transition) and delay it, the jump is reduced.

I'm trying to understand the exact interaction to eliminate the jump without magic number hackery.

Here is a CodePen: https://codepen.io/richardkmichael/pen/abzYOjB

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible").forEach(function(c) {
  c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    this.classList.toggle("collapsed");
  });

  c.addEventListener("transitionrun", function(e) {
    this.classList.add("transitioning");
  });

  c.addEventListener("transitionend", function(e) {
    this.classList.remove("transitioning");

    // Set `display: none;` on contained div?
    // Perhaps unnecessary, since `width: 0`?
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.container {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;

  display: flex;
}

.collapsible {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  
  /* Lengthen transition and/or increase delay to remove jump. */
  /* Permits width/opacity transition to complete? */
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: flex-grow 2.5s 0.5s;
}

.collapsible.collapsed {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.collapsible div {
  outline: 1px solid green;

  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  transition: opacity 2s, width 2s;
}

.collapsed div {
  outline: 1px solid purple;

  opacity: 0;

  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.transitioning div {
  /* Debugging. */
  background: cyan;

  /* Needed during transition to full-size. */
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="collapsible">
    <h3>One</h3>
    <div>This is item 1.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="collapsible">
    <h3>Two</h3>
    <div>This is item 2.</div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<p>
  The aim is to smoothly eliminate the column content, leaving only the header.
</p>

<p>
  Click a column header ("One" or "Two") to collapse the column; click again to expand.</p>

<p>
  What is causing the jump near the end of the collapse or expand transition?
</p>
```

If it helps convey the objective, my use-case is a calendar in week-view, where the days (Mon, etc.) are the columns.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is due to `width:100%` and more precisely the use of percentange value creating a complex calculation in order to resolve it.

You may try to animate `max-width` instead. The only drawback is that you will have a delay at the start when using a big value but you can adjust the transition to rectify this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible").forEach(function(c) {
  c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    this.classList.toggle("collapsed");
  });

  c.addEventListener("transitionrun", function(e) {
    this.classList.add("transitioning");
  });

  c.addEventListener("transitionend", function(e) {
    this.classList.remove("transitioning");

    // Set `display: none;` on contained div?
    // Perhaps unnecessary, since `width: 0`?
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.container {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;

  display: flex;
}

.collapsible {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  
  /* Lengthen transition and/or increase delay to remove jump. */
  /* Permits width/opacity transition to complete? */
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: flex-grow 2.5s 0.5s;
}

.collapsible.collapsed {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.collapsible div {
  outline: 1px solid green;

  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 100vw;
  transition: opacity 2s, max-width 2s;
}

.collapsed div {
  outline: 1px solid purple;

  opacity: 0;

  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.transitioning div {
  /* Debugging. */
  background: cyan;

  /* Needed during transition to full-size. */
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="collapsible">
    <h3>One</h3>
    <div>This is item 1.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="collapsible">
    <h3>Two</h3>
    <div>This is item 2.</div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<p>
  The aim is to smoothly eliminate the column content, leaving only the header.
</p>

<p>
  Click a column header ("One" or "Two") to collapse the column; click again to expand.</p>

<p>
  What is causing the jump near the end of the collapse or expand transition?
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:

On your .collapsed div (around line 46 in your codepen) change:

`width: 0`

to

`width: 0%`

Comment: Interesting, I usually specify unitless `0` so didn't try this.  Now the shrunk width of the column is now [what appears to be] the original width of the content div, despite it being `0`.  Seems the final flex item size is calculated before the browser knows the content div is going to be `0` width.  Thanks for the hint.